# Not able to send mail in ZF2

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-framework2

```
call_user_func($this->callable, $to, $subject, $body, $headers, $params);
```

This was my Function for send mail but it gives following error

> {"error-message":"Unable to send mail: Unknown error","error-trace":[{"function":"mailHandler","class":"Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail","type":"-\u003E","args":["mujahed69@gmail.com","=?UTF-8?Q?Infinia?=","\u003Cdiv\u003Ehello\u003C/div\u003E","Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 09:40:43 +0000\nFrom: =?UTF-8?Q?Infinea=20Team?= \u003Cservice@infiniaretail.de\u003E\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"," -fservice@infiniaretail.de"]},{"file":"/var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php","line":139,"function":"call_user_func","args":[[{"__className":"Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail"}`

Answer (score 0):

use following link, you use custom function. in that function you should be paste same code of this page
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html

Comment: Can i send mail form localhost ?

Comment: you cant send mail from a local server unless it is properly configured

Comment: yeah you can send email from localhost but you have to set email transport via email gateway. ( gmail is better)